# Как протестировать сервис или сделать правильный mock? Java11, Spock Framework

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, groovy, mock

Коллегии, всех приветствую! Подскажите, как решить, либо как поступить. (Java11, SpringBoot, тестирование - Spock Framework) Мне нужно написать тест, который протестирует метод класса, вся проблема в том, что метод тестируемого класса, вызывает другой сервис через наследование, который объявляется не в тестируемом классе, а в его абстрактном предке. Как тестировать такую историю? Если бы этот сервис объявлялся в самом тестируемом классе - то тут все понятно, я бы создал мок в тесте и передал бы его в конструктор, но что делать если этот сервис находится у предка? ниже прикрепляю пример кода

```java
// Класс, который нужно протестировать

@Service
public class ServiceForTest extends AbstractComponent{

    public String methodForTest (String s) {
        return someService.generateString(s);
    }

}

//Абстрактный класс от которого наследуется тестируемый и который содержит сервис

public class AbstractComponent {

    @Autowired
    protected SomeService someService;

}

public interface SomeService {

    String generateString(String s);

}

@Service
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService{

    @Override
    public String generateString(String s) {
        return s;
    }

}
```

А ниже пример, как бы я поступил если бы сервис находился в самом тестируемом классе

```
@Service
public class ServiceForTest extends AbstractComponent{

    final SomeService someService;

    public ServiceForTest(SomeService someService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    public String methodForTest (String s) {
        return someService.generateString(s);
    }

}
```

Тест

```
//тест на groovy, Spock Framework
class ServiceForTestTest extends Specification {

    ServiceForTest serviceForTest

    void setup(){
        SomeService someServiceMock = Mock(SomeService)
        someServiceMock.generateString("TEST") >> "TEST"
        serviceForTest = new ServiceForTest(someServiceMock)
    }

    def "Test for return current value"(){

        when:
        def methodForTest = serviceForTest.methodForTest("TEST")

        then:
        methodForTest == "TEST"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если в у вас проект на Spring может тогда подойдет тестирование при помощи SpringBooTest?
`@SpringBootTest` - пойдет вверх по пакетам (если не перечислить в нем классы которые надо положить в конфиг) в поисках конфигурации (`@Configuration`), найдет конфиг и поднимет контекст по нему. Далее вы можете замокать `SomeService` в контексте аннотацией `@MockBean` (используется `Mockito`). Примерный кода на Junit правда, на счет Spock не знаю может ли он интегрироваться с контекстом Spring-a

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ServiceForTest.class)
class ServiceForTestTest {
    @Autowired
    ServiceForTest serviceForTest;
    @MockBean
    SomeService someService;

    @Test
    private void test(){
       // конфигурация мока
       // test JUnit
    }
}
```